# Does Canadian spousal open work permit get affected if the other spouse with company bound work permit moves countries?

Tags: working-visas, canada, work-permit

I have a friend who is on work permit bound to a company in Canada. His wife has open work permit resulting from his work permit. He will be moving to the US and wondering if his wife can stay in Canada for a while. Is that possible? Will her work permit somehow get cancelled if he leaves the country?